# unable to determine activity name android

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am facing an error regarding the activity stating "unable to determine activity name android. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am new to programming.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the android manifest, the `<activity>` tag states that there is an activity called `hello`.

This means that the hello class must extend `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` (or eventually `ComponentActivity`).

Please read carefully [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)

Comment: if only I could understand....

Answer (score 0):

The java file you wrote is just a pure java file, and to create an app, you need to expand `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity` as Lino said.

Extension is to use the properties of the parent class, for which java uses `extends` keyword. Extension is a very important concept of java, so please study carefully this part later.

Enter the code below and it will run.

Hello.java :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Hello extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);
    }
}
```

activity_hello.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, Android!"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The part where you get the error in Manifest.java :

```
<activity
    android:name=".Hello"
    android:label="Hello Activity">
...
</activity>
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

As Lino and Sarah said is really important to expand the `Activity` class, in your case you have just a `java` file, you also need an `xml` file. An activity is composed by `java` code, and `xml` code. In the `xml` you write the "visual" part, and in the `java` code the "logical" part.
I also have  a shortcut for you, next time you create an activity you can do in the menu bar :

```
File ->  New -> Activity -> Empty Views Activity
```

This will generate the `java` code and the `xml` code automatically, generating an activity.